# Service not finding endpoint

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-service

I'm trying to map an external Postgres box into my Kubernetes cluster using the `Service` and `Endpoint` resources but the service is not detecting the endpoint.

```
terraform $ kubectl describe services postgres -n infrastructure
Name:              postgres
Namespace:         infrastructure
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.222.4.128
Port:              postgres  5432/TCP
TargetPort:        5432/TCP
Endpoints:         
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

The service and endpoint were created with:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: postgres
 namespace: infrastructure
spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 ports:
 - port: 5432
   targetPort: 5432
----
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: postgres
 namespace: infrastructure
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: "10.0.0.1"
   ports:
     - port: 5432
```

I can connect to the Postgres box from a running container if I use the IP for the instance, but not with the Kubernetes service name (`postgres.infrastructure.svc.cluster.local.)`

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your manifest file directly and applied to my cluster without any running pods and I get an endpoint (unlike yours):

```
kubectl describe svc/postgres -n infrastructure
Name:              postgres
Namespace:         infrastructure
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"postgres","namespace":"infrastructure"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":...
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.109.74.181
Port:              <unset>  5432/TCP
TargetPort:        5432/TCP
Endpoints:         10.0.0.1:5432
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

If your "Endpoints" field above is empty, something’s wrong and it's no surprise you can't connect via hostname.

Similarly, hostname lookup works from within a pod on the cluster

```
$ kubectl run --rm '--restart=Never' '--image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent' -i -t '--image=alpine' tmp-29399
# apk-add install --no-cache bind-tools
[output omitted]
# dig +short postgres.infrastructure.svc.cluster.local.
10.109.74.181
```

I'm suspecting something's wrong with your service. Can you run `kubectl describe svc/postgres -n infrastructure` (look at Events section at the end, if exists) to see if there's any problem on `service` syncing from `endpoint` resource.

Also please specify where you're running at. Is this GKE?

Comment: There are no events as can be seen in the output for `kubectl describe` as I gave above. Yes, this is running in GKE 1.10.12 on both master and nodes. I'm upgrading to 1.11.7 now to see if that will resolve it.

Comment: Upgrading didn't fix it.

Comment: Can you try on docker for desktop cluster maybe first?

Comment: Ran it on minikube and it worked fine. I deleted the service and endpoint, restarted the nodes, re-applied and it worked. IDK what was wrong... Thank you though!